# Cannot add human annotators in my Watson Knowledge Studio Beta project

Tags: watson, watson-knowledge-studio

I'm using the WKS Beta in a project, but I couldn't add a human annotator. I've created a task with the added user, but he didn't receive any notification or something in his account.

How may I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does "WKS Beta" mean WKS Experimental on Bluemix?
If so, share the url of the WKS top page with the human annotator (https://.../ui/#/) and he/she can see the task.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you, @hmtbr